# Same click action passing different parameters to mouse listener. Is it possible?

Tags: java, swing

I have a mouse listener for selecting a row in `JTable` in a dialog box say **A**, which has the following code.

```
resultTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() 
    {
        public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
        {
            thePatientFinderController.jTableMouseReleased(evt);
        }
    });
```

and the method, which is called.

```
public void jTableMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
{
   // Business logic
 }
```

I am using the very same `JTable`, in another dialog box say **B**. Now, if I select a row in this dialog box **B**, I want to have the `mouseReleased` to perform different action.

I tried to have another mouseReleased method like this, with different parameters.

```
resultTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() 
    {
        public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
        {
            thePatientFinderController.jTableMouseReleased(evt);
        }
        public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt, int a) 
        {
            thePatientFinderController.jTableMouseReleased(evt,a);
        }
    });
```

It didn't work, it just called the first method. So, I am stuck here.

So, is there any way to call the second method? Are a different logic is needed?

Conclusion: The same button should call different mouseReleased event methods, based on different dialog boxes.

Comment: *Because I tried it, it throws me an error.* - then fix the error. We don't know what the error is or what your code is doing. Programming is about debugging errors. Why did you add a SwingWorker tag? There is no posted code that uses a SwingWorker.

Comment: Oops! typing mistake! I meant to say, it threw a warning saying, this method is never used.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way. Remember: these listeners are called within a framework. That framework only knows the base *MouseListener* interface. It has **no** idea that **you** have some other methods in the class implementing the interface.

Ask yourself: how is the *framework* supposed to know *which* other parameters to acquire, and which method to pick and pass those parameters?!

In other words: if there is only one MouseListener instance, then the code that you put **into** that class/method needs to somehow fetch further context, in case it needs do different "things" based on that context.

Meaning: either you have ONE listener that fetches context, and decides what to do, or (probably the cleaner design): you implement **different** mouse listeners, and depending on context, the "matching" mouse listener gets used.

Comment: Implement different mouse listeners means? I am not getting you. Can you explain pls?

Comment: You can add/remove listeners dynamically. So instead of having ONE listener that does two things, have TWO different listener implementations that each do different things.

Comment: Superb!!! can you pull out a small code snippet from your hat...Because I tried it, it throws me an error.

Comment: Not really. You see, you already wrote the code to implement that interface. So why would you need another example ... showing you what you already did. Also note: avoid coming back with new questions in comments. If you really have a new question, ask a new question. Read [mcve] and add all relevant information to that new question. 
Beyond that: it seems that you really lack basic knowledge of java. Are you sure you are ready for programming a GUI application? Swing is a complicated framework, and for people who really lack the basics ... that is hard. You will run from one problem into ...

Comment: the next. I would rather advise you to step back. For example by first carefully reading/working the oracle tutorial on the swing components, or even: java basics.